# Внешний ADC с буфером на Arduino

Tags: tcp, arduino, fifo, buffer

Необходимо считывать с помощью Ардуино (мега либо дуе) аналоговый сигнал примерно раз в 10-100нс (не меньше 200нс точно) в течении секунды, в последствии чего послать полученные данные на сервер (отправляются по TCP). Понятное дело, что само ардуино на такое чтение не способно, да и хранить столько данных до отправки она не может, а значит надо использовать внешний ADC и какой-то буфер для него. Можете подсказать возможные варианты ADC с буфером или какие-то ещё варианты?

Comment: Вам бы с частотой определиться, у вас вилка от 5 мегагерц до 100. Многовато как-то.

Comment: Пускай для начала будет 50нс. Этот вопрос больше из интереса, поэтому такой большой разброс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея такая - берете нужный АЦП, берете нужную RAM, берете то, что справится с генерацией адресов на нужной частоте (микроконтроллер, толпу рассыпухи, ПЛИС), соединяете это барахло нужными дорогами и готово.

Есть АЦП с параллельным выводом, есть RAM с параллельным IO, достаточно соединить их линии данных, выход DATA_READY с АЦП пустить на вход счетчика, линии которого идут на адресные линии RAM - и готово. Тут даже контроллер по сути не нужен.